# In Java, why is it that a Stack is a concrete class whereas the Queue is an interface?

Tags: stack, queue

Which one of Queue's subclasses is a 'plain ordinary' queue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) java.util.Stack is a legacy class from Java 1.0. It predates the Collections framework by many years, and it's frankly an example of *horrible* design on many fronts. Nothing about it is the way things should be. The main problem is that `Stack` extends `Vector`, and as all inheritance in Java is public inheritance, all the methods of `Vector` are available on `Stack` as well. Therefore, you can inspect any position in a Stack, add and remove elements from the middle, clear it, or do any number of other things that should not be part of a stack abstraction, *without a cast*. Contrast that to using the `Queue` or `Deque` interfaces, through which only stack-appropriate methods are available.

(2) There really is no such thing as a plain ordinary queue, but LinkedList implements Queue without any special semantics, so maybe that's what you want.

Comment: can you explain why `java.util.Stack` is a *horrible* design?  ...especially in the context of why `java.util.Queue` is well-designed?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Any of its concrete subclasses can be used as a "plain ordinary" queue.  True, they may have additional functionality, but you're free to use only the methods declared in the `Queue` interface.  Though I imagine you might want to avoid the subclasses whose extra functionality affect queue ordering (like `PriorityQueue`), capacity, etc. if you want an "ordinary" one.

Comment: Except that many of the subclasses do things that are far from plain and ordinary. For example, SynchronousQueue has zero internal capacity.